# Hypergraph to graph preserving automorphisms

Tags: graph-theory

Given a hypergraph, is there a general way to turn it into a stantard graph (i.e, one were the edges are just pairs of vertices) preserving the automorphism group? At first I thought you could just exchange every hyperedge by a complete subgraph but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a general construction which takes a group $G$ and produces a graph whose automorphism group is $G$, so at worst one could calculate the automorphism group of the hypergraph and then apply the general construction.  But from your description I suppose you want a simpler construction that operates directly on the hypergraph without explicitly calculating the automorphism group first.

Comment: That's right :), thanks anyway.